# NO PUEDO SUBIR UNA IMAGEN DESDE MI FRONT CON VUE

Tags: nodejs, vue.js, express, vuetify, multer

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy tratando de subir una imagen con vuejs, tengo mi backend ya funcionando correctamente con multer y clodinary y agrega la imagen con postman.

Pero cuando quiero subir desde mi frontend con vuejs me sale error de PATH como undefine
no se si también instalar y configurar multer en mi frontend o solo basta con el backend

Por favor si alguien me pueda indicar cual es la solución o si tienen algunos ejemplos.
o si tienen otro método de hacerlo les agradezco.

```
 <v-dialog
      v-model="dialog"
      max-width="500px"
      persistent
    >
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>
          <span class="headline">Categorias</span>
        </v-card-title>
      <v-form @submit.prevent="agregarImages()">
        <v-card-text>
          <v-container>
            <v-row>
              <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="12">
                <v-text-field outlined dense label="Nombre" v-model="images.nombre" required></v-text-field>
              </v-col>

               <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="12">
                  <v-file-input
                    label="Insertar Imagent"
                    filled
                    type="file"
                    v-model="images.file"
                    prepend-icon="mdi-camera"
                  ></v-file-input>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-container>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn color="red" text @click="close">Cancelar</v-btn>
          <v-btn class="ma-2" outlined color="indigo" type="submit">Guardar</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
        </v-form>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>



  methods: {

  agregarImages() {
    let config = {
        headers: {
          token: this.token
        }
      }
      console.log(this.images);
      this.axios.post('/images/upload', this.images, config)
        .then(res => {
            this.imagenes.push(res.data)
            this.images.nombre = '';
            this.images.file = '';              
            this.dialog=false
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e.response);
        })
},

close () {
    this.dialog = false
  },

},
```

```js
   export default {
    data: () => ({
    images:{
            nombre:'',
            path:'',
            },
}
```

[image: ERROR EN MI BACK]

Comment: Escribe el mensaje de error _como texto, con formato_. En imágenes, es prácticamente ilegible. Lee [ask].

Comment: que sale aca? console.log(this.images);